# How to get protoc to compile a proto with its dependencies?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I need to fix a grpc service, so I want to understand the logic around compiling them.

In the example below, I don't understand why protoc doesn't compile the `address.proto`, since it's imported by `person.proto`.

There are no build errors, so I don't think it's an import/naming issue. Unfortunately, only a `person_pb2.py` is generated...

```proto
// file: address.proto

syntax="proto3";

message Address {
    string city = 1;
    string road = 3;
    int32 roadNumber = 4;
}
```

```proto
// file: person.proto

syntax="proto3";

import "address.proto";

message Person {
  string name = 1;
  Address home = 3;
  Address work = 4;
}
```

build command:

```sh
python -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path ../protos --python_out=. person.proto
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reasonable question.

The answer is that you're only asking `protoc` to compile `person.proto` (and it's taking you literally). But, the generated code won't run because `person_pb2.py` depends on `address_pb2`:

```py
import address_pb2 as address__pb2
```

You need to have Python sources for **all** protocol buffers types that your code needs.

```py
python3 \
-m grpc_tools.protoc \
--proto_path=../protos \
--python_out=. \
person.proto address.proto
```

A good example of this problem (being solved) is Google's so-called [Well-Known Types (WKTs)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf)

You could include e.g. `google.protobuf.Timestamp` in `Person` by adding `import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto"`:

```proto
syntax="proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "address.proto";

message Person {
  string name = 1;
  Address home = 3;
  Address work = 4;
  google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 5;
}
```

And you can `protoc` **without change** and your code will work.

This is because Google bundles the WKTs **and** generated Python code with `grpcio-tool`. As with any other source, you **do** need to import the Google-provided Python sources to use the code.

To do this, you must

`main.py`:

```
import address_pb2
import person_pb2

from google.protobuf.timestamp_pb2 import Timestamp
```

So, where are these files?

In my case:

```
lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc_tools/_proto/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto
```

And:

```
lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb2.py
```

> **NOTE**
> It's convenient that Google bundles the generated sources but this is not required and it creates two potential problems.
>
> 1. `timestamp.proto` is the source-of-truth and we must assume|trust that `google/protobuf/timestamp_pb2.py` was generated from it.
> 2. If we're the proto developer, we're expected to produce sources for all languages that our proto's developers may use every time we update the protos.
>
> For these reasons, generally (!) developers provide only the protos and don't include generated sources and assume that you're able to plug the proto into `protoc` and generated the perfect facsimile as code yourself.